Future in the past with past simple verb
the next time I would be in the area was on tour for my solo project, Judy and the Zipper who was planning a two-week tour with another band called XX.
I 've read this sentence on a record cover  and I am wondering :Why "was on tour" and not would be on tour, it is also future in the past. Is it to avoid a repetition of would be .The reader knows that this event is in future in the past because of would be .Is it possible that the author wrote "was on tour" to make the reader understand that "would be" is not a conditional but a future in THE PAST. The event is finished

I agree that 'would be on tour' looks (and reads) better, but the text on record covers is very often not the most formal of writing, and rock musicians are not always (or very often) inclined or able to write in formal school grammar book style.

Are there missing punctuation marks in the first paragraph, after project?

Is it the same for " was planning"?

What @SeowjoohengSingapore said. Except the cited text is inherently invalid, and can't be "fixed" just by adding some punctuation. Presumably "my next project" is called "Judy", but even if it's actually called "Judy and the Zipper", the relative clause who was... can't work here. The only syntactically valid interpretation is if the name of "my next project" is everything that follows those words, but pragmatically that seems like a ridiculous project name.

yes the name of his solo project is judy and the zipper

... who was planning...
The name of a project can't be planning a tour.
As what @FumbleFingers said, the cited text is invalid.
It's not worth our effort to analyse any further.

The sentence is elliptical:

The next time I would be in the area was [when I was] on tour for my solo project.

The prepositional phrase "on tour" doesn't specify a time but an activity or status of sorts, what the speaker was doing, not when, the conditions under which they were in the area again.
The speaker is using future-in-past with "I would be in the area" but normal time-line tensing when specifying the occasion of being in the area with "was [when I was] on tour for my solo project...".
Compare:

The next time I would go to that amusement park was on my 11th birthday.

P.S. With respect to what comes after "my solo project" ...
I assume the writer is involved in music production in some way and was working with the band or artist "Judy and the Zipper", who was planning a two-week tour:
.... Judy and the Zipper [comma here] who was planning a two-week tour...
Again, the writer is being elliptical, leaving out [when I was working | being a roadie | setting up the sound system | whatever].
P.P.S. A future-in-past construction has a timeline of transpired events as its terra firma. The temporal perspective is shifted from NOW to a point back in time, somewhere along that timeline, and the perspective from that point is looking forward to a then yet-to-happen event. The relative clause refers to the then yet-to-happen event with a modal verb (that I would be in the area) but the matrix clause uses simple past The next time ... was when I was on tour. The matrix clause is tethered to terra firma.

Why is it possible to use" was "in your example and not would be . Both parts of the sentence happen at  the same time

Please see the P.P.S. that I've appended.

will it be possible in your example to use also would be :
The next time I would go to that amusement park would be on my 11th birthday

Is this structure often used "would be for the relative clause and past simple for the Matrix clause"

@YvesLefol  The next time I would go to that amusement park would be on my 11th birthday is not ungrammatical, but it puts "my 11th birthday" in the future-in-past too. Narrative can become quite complex, with multiple layers of time.  My example with the modal verb in the relative clause and simple past in the matrix clause is relatively simple, time-layer-wise.
